# Three.JS Library FontLoader Not Loading Specific Letters

Tags: javascript, three.js

While working with three.js, i tried using the text geometry (im a beginner just started three.js recently) with the fontloader but only specific letters are loading like C, O, S meanwhile N, L, E are not loading

here is the code for the following

```
const loader = new FontLoader();

const textmaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial()
textmaterial.size = 0.1
textmaterial.sizeAttenuation = true;


loader.load( '/font.json', function ( font ) {
  const textgeometry = new TextGeometry('CONSOLEE', {
    size: 1,
    height: 12,
    font: font,
    weight: 'regular',
    style: 'normal',
    curveSegments: 24,
    bevelSize: 0,
    bevelThickness: 2,
    bevelEnabled: false,
    anchor: {
      x: 0.5,
      y: 0.5,
      z: 0.0
    }
  })
  const text = new THREE.Points( textgeometry, textmaterial)
  scene.add( text );
})
```

[this is what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmAVQ.png)

also /font.json is a file that i converted from ttf to static json

Comment: Perhaps *"font.json is a file that i converted from ttf to static json"* is where it went wrong?

Comment: i tried using https://unpkg.com/three@0.77.0/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json as well and it didn't work so i don't think that was the issue